A good rising edge D Flip Flop CMOS implementation
I'm currently trying to create a basic CPU with SOT32 CMOS transistors. I have made a good design and architecture and began testing and ordering PCB's. However, I found that there are a lot of rising edge D Flip Flop circuits that I can implement.
Sadly, I can't seem to find the design I'm looking for. My main concern is to limit the amount of transistors per flip flop. I also want a RESET input on the DFF.
So if anyone knows a good design, it would be really helpful!

Do you have FETs with or without a separate body contact? What's the part number?

I use MOSFETs so that would be with separate body contact. I use the NMOS 2n7002 and PMOS AO3401

The parts you listed don't have separate body (bulk) contacts. They're internally connected to source. This makes building flipflops from them a lot more difficult as you can't easily build pass gates.

I wasn’t aware of that. But why does this affect pass gates?
